# How to appeal against and remove restrictions on asking questions

Tags: discussion

I have just attempted to ask a question in the regular site but before i was able to i was prompted that my previous questions had been poorly recieved and that i should think about my question before i ask it. I have had several questions that have been uprated and my last question had been responded by a member as a good question.That question has since not been answered by anyone significantly and has not been provided with a definite answer. I am confused are people being punished for asking question that the scientific community don't have answers to. I think this is a narrow minded attitude and i hope others have not suffered as i have. and have not been put off by members answering question they cant answer by a simple statement "we do not know currently" and then putting restrictions on them asking further questions

Comment: If your questions aren't getting answered it's almost certainly because they aren't clear. Asking questions well is difficult. If you need inspiration, read through some highly upvoted questions, or come to the chat room and ask for help there.

Comment: @DanielSank no offence Daniel but i think dmckee answer below was more diplomatic and i didnt get the downvote aswell.

Comment: You think I down-voted this post? Perhaps you should not make baseless accusations :)

Comment: @DanielSank calm down mate this is not a international court of law i do not completely understand the rating all i saw was i had a minus 1 next to the question i asked, and since you were the last person to comment i attributed it to you i am not challenging your integrity.

Comment: *"and since you were the last person to comment i attributed it to you"* Please reconsider that form of reasoning when using this site. It is a common mistake. I also hope you will re-read dmckee's answer, because as far as I can tell, your interpretation of it is not a good representation of what I think he's trying to tell you.

Comment: @DanielSank Look mate i'am not a child and ive admitted i do not understand how the ratings happen but i do not appreciate the tone of you criticism leave that for the school yard dude. As for dmkee i understand perfectly what he was describing.

Comment: Relevant post on Meta Stack Exchange: [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th).

Comment: Thankyou @Emilio Pisanty all i asked for was a means to approach my situation and to resolve it.

Comment: @8Mad0Manc8 In short: fix (not delete) your closed questions if you can, and stop asking bad questions. A significant dose of antidote against paranoia and a bit of forethought before making baseless accusations would also help.

Comment: @Emilio Pisanty Touche!! :-)

Answer (score 8):

By the sound of it, you have not actually been subjected to an automated question ban (or, if you have, it was short-lived), you've just come close enough that you triggered a system warning. Three of your seven (non-deleted) questions were closed; please take the warning as a prompt to look at those closed questions and understand why they were closed.

If you can edit [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/179067/age-of-the-universe) into something coherent that contains an actual on-topic question then that will certainly help with the prospect of a question ban. Please take the closure of [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/229487/faster-than-the-speed-of-light) as a sign of some things that don't really fly here ("I know this has been asked a million times before, and I know it's off-topic, but yo, check this out, if you break physics then physics breaks" ring a bell?), and please take [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/177618/why-should-i-believe-that-matter-does-not-expand-along-with-the-space-between-it) as a reminder that if you know the question has been asked before then you do need to check for duplicates.

From what I can see, this is the automated system working as designed: you have produced a significant fraction of off-topic questions, and it is asking you to think carefully about your next posts before the site actually stops taking questions from your IP address.

And, if I may: lashing out against the community for being "narrow minded" and punishing people for "asking question that the scientific community don't have answers to" is hardly a way to make friends. In particular, your closed questions are well short of the mark in terms of the amount of thought that you need to put into them before you can really claim that you're challenging the established scientific consensus. You're being told that you need to put in the time yourself before you go asking others to put in theirs, and I would counsel you to listen to that. It's OK to express frustration (though not in the rude way that you're doing it now), but you do need to step up to the fact that you've asked bad questions, period.

Comment: I am in the freends making business my response was for a presumed  unsolicited attack on the validity of my questions and as such the restriction was placed upon me and i stated that a member of your cummunity had accepted as a valid question and stated was a good question. This was an example of validity of my questions and i could not understand the imposed penalty systematic or not on my ability to pose questions. I certainly did not expect this response to my outburst as i it .But i do not admit it was called for and i indicated this but it pales into insignificance the response from it.

Answer (score 4):

Your profile does not show that you are currently affected by any unusual restrictions.

That said, the [contact us](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/contact) link at the bottom of each page allows you to contact the Stack Exchange community-wide moderation team.

Comment: Thankyou Iam sorry for my outburst i didn't think that i deserved a restriction and my reaction was as a result of this. Should it persist ill use the contact us link as suggested thankyou.

Comment: Don't misunderstand. I didn't change anything for you. At one time you were affected by a totally automated restriction, that has subsequently been automatically relaxed. If you cross its line again, it will take effect again, and there is nothing I can do about it. This is part of the built-in behaviors of Stack Exchange site and it is meant to  either encourage you to contribute good content or to strongly throttle how much poor content you can contribute.

Comment: Glad to hear its a systematic problem and not a personal one :)

Comment: @8Mad0Manc8: It's __not__ a _systematic problem_; it is rather a warning to improve your posts and ameliorate the quality of your queries. But surely, it's not _personal_ either.

Comment: @MAFIA36790 you would think its not personal but judging by how my posed questions since i asked this question have been mutilated and my score has been reduced significantly iam beggining to think it is. Even though I apologised for the outburst in an above comment.

Comment: @8Mad0Manc8 By posting the above you called the attention of various members of the community to the material you have posted up until now. They went and looked at your posting history (after all, how else were they suppose to judge if you had a legitimate complaint or not?), and presumably then they judged what they saw. Which is how it is suppose to work: Stack Exchange sites use crowd-sourced evaluation to sort out the best (and incidentally the uninspired, the poor and the truly awful) posts. This is sometimes called the "meta effect" in parallel to the "Streisand Effect".

Comment: @dmckee yes I gathered my comments had brought a lot of attention and i understand you need to use computer algorithms to monitor the site and when i said systematic problem

Comment: @dmckee (continuing)that was not exactly what i meant. I was a bit upset by questions had been altered since they where excepted when i post them. I will take what has been said onboard and hope my future question will be written more coherently. I will add when i post questions the are written as I am thinking of them and as such are disjointed and not structured. Anyway no hard feelings and by the way is the Striesand effect named after Barbara? :-)